# Libgdx won't render on requestRendering

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop

I'm making a match-three based game where each time the user moves a piece in the board, the game do the following cicle:

```
do {
    checkIfThereAre3BlocksTogether();
    removeThoseBlocks();
    updateTheBoardPieces();

    showTheBoard();
} while (thereWhereBlockRemoved);
```

This is mainly because when you remove some pieces, there is the chance that a fallen piece make a combination an so on...

The problem I'm facing is that I can't make that the board get rendered between each iteration of this loop. I get only the final result of this loop.

What I tried is to make a Thread.sleep( 2 * 1000) before each iteration in order to give time to the render system to draw my board but it work.

Another workaround is to call

```
 Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

and then call to:

```
 Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

in the showTheBoard() function... I put some system.out.println in the render function in order to know if it was called and I realized that the render is only called when the do/while loop exits. (Despite this situation, render is called correctly)

Just in case it helps, in my Screen implementation, I have this code in my render function at this moment:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    System.out.println("Rendering");

    // Background rendering
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    // World rendering
    renderer.render();
}
```

I think the problem can be related to thread handling. I undestood that libgdx make rendering in a different thread but this situation is like I have only one thread that has to wait the computation ends before rendering...

If anybody can give some hint about what could be happening, I would appreciate!

Comment: it isnt advisable to make the thread sleep .... try for other methods...

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx will invoke its `render` callback once per frame.  You cannot get Libgdx to draw multiple frames from within a single `render` callback, so your while loop will always run to completion before the next frame is rendered to the screen.

You need to switch from the `while` loop to an approach that expects `render` to be called multiple times over the course of the update.  Generally, a state machine is a good way to way to think about this problem.  But in your specific case, I think you can just get rid of the while loop entirely.  (Effectively the `render` method is already in an infinite while loop):

```
public void render(float delta) {
    ...
    if (checkIfThereAre3BlocksTogether()) {
       removeThoseBlocks();
       updateTheBoardPieces();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you may run into the problem that while you are running through these updates, you will want to prevent the player from making new changes to the system.  You will need to track the "mode" your game is in (accepting updates or running through combos) and postpone checking input until you have finished running through the combos.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, your suggestion is to move the game logic into the render function. I thought it was used for drawing only. My loop was called when two pieces moved (mouse/touch input) so I had the game logic separated from the drawing. But I'll follow your approach and let you know!

Comment: Yeah, despite the name the `render` function is the routine that is called once per frame update, and it is where you should update your world and do your rendering.